# How to prevent socket channel split on 1399 bytes?

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I have a C# client that send and receive data from the Java socket server. When the output data from the server to the client overpass 1399 it gets received in 2 parts:

1. First part: 0-1399 bytes
2. Second part: The rest

Is there any way to prevent it from splitting?

Code for server side:

```
if(outData.size() == 0) return;
try {
    if(!socketChannel.isOpen()) return;

    byte[] bytesArray = outData.toByteArray();
    outData.reset();

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytesArray.length);

    buffer.put(bytesArray);
    buffer.flip();
    socketChannel.write(buffer);

} catch (IOException e) {
    disconnect();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code for client side:

```
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
recieveBuffer = new byte[8142];

try
{
    clientSocket.Connect("111.111.111.111",9889));
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
    Debug.Log(ex.Message);
}
clientSocket.BeginReceive(recieveBuffer,0,recieveBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),null);
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to prevent this, as this happens because it needs two (or more) network packets, and therefor the read may return when the first packet is received.

Comment: Packets simply have a maximum size; it's up to you to check for that and paste them together. That's why there are protocols that either rely on specific start/end boundary bytes, or which send the size (and possibly checksum) along with the data.